# Origin and part of speech of 'for that matter'

Tags: phrases, parts-of-speech

What is the origin of the phrase 'for that matter'?

And what part of speech does it function as?

It's obviously a modifier, but it seems to me to modify the whole sentence. In fact…If I say "He was taller than me. For that matter, he was wider too." --the sense of 'for that matter' in the second sentence depends upon the first sentence. So as a modifier 'for that matter' seems to connect two sentences. Mind you, there are a few phrases that work like that, 'on the contrary' or 'on the other hand' being examples. None of them work semantically in stand-alone sentences.

Comment: "On the other hand" and "On the contrary" can occur in stand-alone sentences, I think. For example: "On one hand, he wanted to go. On the other hand, he knew he would be disappointed" seem okay to me... Consider also sentential modifiers like "As a result, ..." Here is a page on "sentential adverbs": https://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/the-open-secret-of-sentential-adverbs/

Comment: The full OED has ***(as) for that matter:** so far as that is concerned (more recently also introducing an additional supporting observation, **esp. one offered in refutation of a position**).* Their first citation is 1575 (with ***as***), and the second is 1633: *Mine enemies gave it out to my disgrace that I was his horse-keepers boy. But **for that matter** I shall referre my selfe unto the report of the Count.*

Comment: @Silenus, I mean 'stand alone' in the sense that they can act as a modifier without the need for a prior sentence. If, with no context, I said, "On the other hand, Sarah seems nice", you would ask, "On the other hand to what?" I'm aware that this issue of meaning flowing from sentence to sentence is a tricky one…there are very few sentences that don't implicitly refer to previous sentences.

Comment: @Silenus, 'sentential modifier' seems a useful term. How well established is it as a term? And could we talk about 'paragraph modifiers? Consider this: the paragraph I am constructing here is modified by 'consider this'. The whole paragraph is affected by it, not just the initial sentence. And so I think 'consider this' is a paragraph modifier...

Comment: @FumbleFingers, interesting that the example you give wouldn't quite make sense in modern usage, although it makes complete sense semantically, whereas the modern usage no longer quite makes sense but has devolved to an idiom.

Comment: The modern idiomatic sense is OED's *more recently also **introducing an additional supporting observation**, esp. one offered in refutation of a position*, for which their earliest citation seems to be *The Times* 1898: *The..shivering drivers..who **(like every one else, for that matter)** had to lie out in it [sc. the rain] without tents.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, so that possibly represents an innovation by The Times. There's a fine line between innovating and being plain wrong… :-)  I'm twisting my brain into a pretzel trying to see how the quote makes semantic sense if you apply 'for that matter' in the original usage. Perhaps it's a case of a similar location in a narrative text being taken as the same sense.

Comment: @Dunsanist: The way people ask/answer questions about "origin of a usage" here on ELU sometimes gives the impression that "first recorded use" actually ***was*** the first use of some new form (but apart from a handful of neologistic coinages, that's almost never the case). I've no doubt the usage we're dealing with here was already widespread in speech before *The Times* decided it was "current" enough for them to employ it in print. *The drivers had to lie in the rain (but so far as that is concerned, so did everyone else)*.

Comment: ...besides, I don't think the OED's cite *is* a very early one (for that matter! :). Here's Walter Scott's [St Ronan's Well](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Sir+Bungy+too+for+that+matter%22) over 70 years earlier... *“Twa pleasant men, doctor,” said the widow, “and so is Sir Bungy too for that matter”.*